# Pandas HDFStore weird behaviour

Tags: python, pandas, hdfstore

I'm very confused by this, I have two scripts running from the same Notebook server. I have a HDFStore in the same folder, however for one script it looks empty and for the other it doesn't. Here is the same code run in both notebooks:

```
import os 
os.getcwd()
```

Return NB 1: 'E:\DoingDataScience\Identify\Scripts'

Return NB 2: 'E:\DoingDataScience\Identify\Scripts'

```
store = pd.HDFStore('data_test.h5')
store.items
```

Return NB 1:

```
<bound method HDFStore.items of <class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: data_test.h5
/test_database            frame        (shape->[3,5])>
```

Return NB 2:

```
<bound method HDFStore.items of <class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: data_test.h5
Empty>
```

All the circumstances look the same. Does it keep track of the source of the Pandas DF? I thought it was maybe due the file already being opened by NB 1 because NB 1 created it. However killing NB 1 and restarting NB 2 didn't do anything either.

EDIT: Added os.stats:

NB 1 and NB 2 both:

```
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0L, st_nlink=0, 
st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=1311400L, st_atime=1465072325L, 
st_mtime=1465149771L, st_ctime=1465072325L)
```

Update: Now after restarting I'm getting a new error:

HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

File "C:\aroot\work\hdf5-1.8.15-patch1\src\H5F.c", line 604, in H5Fopen
    unable to open file
  File "C:\aroot\work\hdf5-1.8.15-patch1\src\H5Fint.c", line 1085, in H5F_open
    unable to read superblock
  File "C:\aroot\work\hdf5-1.8.15-patch1\src\H5Fsuper.c", line 294, in H5F_super_read
    unable to load superblock
  File "C:\aroot\work\hdf5-1.8.15-patch1\src\H5AC.c", line 1320, in H5AC_protect
    H5C_protect() failed.
  File "C:\aroot\work\hdf5-1.8.15-patch1\src\H5C.c", line 3574, in H5C_protect
    can't load entry
  File "C:\aroot\work\hdf5-1.8.15-patch1\src\H5C.c", line 7954, in H5C_load_entry
    unable to load entry
  File "C:\aroot\work\hdf5-1.8.15-patch1\src\H5Fsuper_cache.c", line 476, in H5F_sblock_load
    truncated file: eof = 800, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eoa = 1181448

End of HDF5 error back trace

Unable to open/create file 'data_test.h5'

Comment: Can you print the file location of the HDStore in each case?  Are you sure it is really the same file?

Comment: How can I obtain that? store.filename just returns the name, not the path

Comment: can you post an output of `os.stat('data_test.h5')` from both Notebooks? The file should not be locked when it's open in one NB

Comment: most probably you've written something into your HDF storage in the NB1 session and didn't close it, so it hasn't yet been flushed to disk

Comment: That might be it... should I open the store, do something with it and then close it immediately?

Comment: you can't read new data from `h5` file (from disk) until you close the store which was used for writing/changing the `h5` file

Comment: Ok good to know. If you turn it into a short answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you've written your data

```
/test_database            frame        (shape->[3,5])>
```

in the NB1's session and didn't close the `store` (which would save and flush your changes to file/disk)

So when you opened your `h5` file in NB2, it wasn't yet flushed and therefore was empty.

Comment: How do you save and flush changes to disk? I have a similar error when I use `df.to_hdf(path, ...)` ?